# Springboot & Thymeleaf HTML template : Chinese characters disappear after converting to PDF

Tags: spring-boot, utf-8, thymeleaf

We re producing pdf invoices out of html templates.

But when the html text is in chinese, there is an issue with the outcome.

The special characters do not show despite the settings with UTF-8.

Here is the html template :

[image]

here is the outcome: 
[image]

We set the UTF-8 encoding in the template resolver and the html template header.

What are we missing?

html template

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

    <head>
        <title>风标汽车租赁服务收据</title>
               <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
     ....
</html>
```

and the template resolver :

```
@Bean
public FileTemplateResolver fileTemplateResolver() throws URISyntaxException {
    FileTemplateResolver fileTemplateResolver = new FileTemplateResolver();
    fileTemplateResolver.setPrefix(getPath());
    fileTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode("LEGACYHTML5");
    fileTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    fileTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    fileTemplateResolver.setOrder(1);
    return fileTemplateResolver;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ve found a solution by downloading the ttc file for simsun and adding it in the project resources.

Then I add it to the fonts of the renderer as below:

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();

        ITextFontResolver resolver = renderer.getFontResolver();
        final ClassPathResource fonts = new ClassPathResource("fonts/simsun.ttc");
        resolver.addFont(fonts.getPath(), BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        renderer.setDocumentFromString(processedHtml);
        renderer.layout();
        renderer.createPDF(byteArrayOutputStream, false);
        renderer.finishPDF();
```

Make also sure that you remove the filtering true from the pom.xml otherwise Spring corrupts the binary ttc file.

```
        <resources> 
            <resource> 
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory> 
                <filtering>true</filtering>   -- remove this line
            </resource> 
        </resources>
```

I hope it helps